# wxPython remove padding/borders

Tags: python, wxpython

As seen in the picture below, there are white spaces between the edges of the windows and the webviews, as well as between the webviews. The webviews are contained in a `wx.Frame` each. Any idea on how to remove these?
[image]

To reproduce this issue:

```
import wx 
import wx.html2 

class MyBrowser(wx.Frame): 
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwds): 
    wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds) 
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL) 
    self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self) 
    sizer.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.EXPAND, 10) 
    self.SetSizer(sizer) 
    self.SetSize((700, 700)) 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  app = wx.App() 
  dialog = MyBrowser(None, -1) 
  dialog.browser.LoadURL("http://www.google.com") 
  dialog.Show() 
  app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: If you put them in a single frame you may have more luck but it's difficult to know, without being able to see your code. Edit your code into the question. Merry Christmas!

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I've included enough code to reproduce the issue. Merry Christmas to you too!

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `10` in the sizer border instruction with 0.

> Add (self, window, proportion=0, flag=0, border=0, userData=None)

Because the webpage is scrollable, you'll always have the scrollbars dividing the windows but the gap can be reduced to nothing.

```
import wx 
import wx.html2 

class MyBrowser(wx.Frame): 
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwds): 
    wx.Dialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwds) 
    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL) 
    self.browser = wx.html2.WebView.New(self) 
    self.browser2 = wx.html2.WebView.New(self) 
    sizer.Add(self.browser, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0) 
    sizer.Add(self.browser2, 1, wx.EXPAND, 0) 
    self.SetSizer(sizer) 

if __name__ == '__main__': 
  app = wx.App() 
  dialog = MyBrowser(None, -1, "Test Double Browser") 
  dialog.browser.LoadURL("http://www.duckduckgo.com") 
  dialog.browser2.LoadURL("http://www.duckduckgo.com") 
  dialog.Show() 
  app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: I'm beginning to think it's an OS issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H3pr.png
Scrollbars aside, there are still white borders around the edge of the window and between the webviews.

Comment: @JTpotato You may be correct, the backend depends on the OS. I use Linux, thus the GTK backend. MS and OSX use different backends. You can specify the backend to use in the call to `New()` (unknown results) and you can also specify a `style` for the window. Perhaps specifying `style=wx.BORDER_NONE` might help.

Comment: This could be a bug specific to WebView2. You're right, I've tested on Pop!_OS and the GTK backend works fine. `style=wx.BORDER_NONE` does nothing for the webview and just creates a borderless window. I think the next logical step would be to create a Github issue and see if anybody could help me there.